# IQueryable where iterating (this or this or this)

Tags: linq, iqueryable

I have a dynamic list of values, which i want to query against an IQueryable with OR conditions.

How would I foreach the values to "OR" them up against the IQueryable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a `List<T>` and then use the `.Contains()` method which would replace your 'or' behaviour.

shed me some light on the code that you already have and I can write you something.